# Display separate robots.txt if host is subdomain (one server block)

Tags: nginx, robots.txt

I have created 2 separate robot.txt files: `robots.txt` and `disabled-robots.txt`

I have one server block with alias in my nginx config. What I am trying to achieve is:

- example.com/robots.txt => robots.txt
- v2.example.com/robots.txt => disabled-robots.txt

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name v2.example.com example.com;

    location = /robots.txt {
       // I think I need to update here, but confused about what I should put

       // if ($host == v2.example.com) {
       //     show disabled-robots.txt
       // } else {
       //     show robots.txt
       // }
    }
}
```

All the examples I have found on StackOverflow shows 2 separate server blocks, however I want to keep my one server block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use the `if` inside a `location` (which has [problems in this context](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)), use a `map` with `try_files` instead.

For example:

```
map $host $which_robot {
    default         /robots.txt;
    v2.example.com  /disabled-robots.txt;
}
server {
    ...

    location = /robots.txt {
        root /path/to/directory;
        try_files $which_robot =404;
    }
}
```

Note that `map` must be declared outside the `server` block. See [the map documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).